# Loading module with dynlink re-initialises top-level values

Tags: ocaml

I have a problem where I have a global hashtable, and then I load a .cma file with Dynlink, which registers a function in the hashtable.

However, the behaviour I seem to be see is that when the module is dynamically linked, all the global bindings get re-initialised, such that my hashtable is empty.

E.g.:

```
Table.extensions : (string, string -> string) Hashtbl.t
Extensions.load : unit -> unit (* loads the specified .cma files *)
Extensions.register : string -> (string -> string) -> unit
  (* adds entry to Table.extensions, prints name of extension registered *)
Main:
let () =
  Extensions.load ();
  Hashtbl.iter (fun x _ -> print_endline x) Table.extensions;
  Printf.printf "%d extensions loaded\n" (Hashtbl.length Table.extensions)
```

My program loads one .cma file, so it *should* print:

```
Registered extension 'test'
test
1 extensions loaded
```

Instead I get:

```
Registered extension 'test'
0 extensions loaded
```

I've been fighting this for several hours now; no matter how I refactor my code, I get no closer to a working solution.

EDIT: Extensions.load:

```
Dynlink.allow_unsafe_modules true;;

let load () =
  try
    let exts = Sys.readdir "exts" in
    Array.iter begin fun name ->
      try
        Dynlink.loadfile (Filename.concat "exts" name);
        Printf.printf "Loaded %s\n" name;
      with
        | Dynlink.Error error -> print_endline (Dynlink.error_message error)
        | exn -> print_endline (Printexc.to_string exn)
      end exts
  with _ -> ()
```

Comment: Are you sure that extension registers itself in the same hashtbl that is used by main program? I.e. isn't it possible that there are two instances of `Table.extenstions`?

Comment: Can you post a little more code?  Specifically it would be helpful to see what `Extensions.load` is doing.

Comment: Two instances of Table.extensions? If this is so, how would I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ygrek, you were right, there were two instances.

The solution was to build/load just the `.cmo`, not a `.cma`.